# DXF export option doesn't respond

Tags: export, osx, blender-id

I have an issue with exporting a drawing to DXF format. I generated a DXF file using some Python script which I can import in Blender without problems, however, after editing this drawing in blender (and converting all objects into a mesh) I want to export the result in DXF again for further use (laser cutting). After selecting the export option nothing happens. I'm using Blender 3.4.1 on a mac with os Ventura 13.4.1.

Any suggestions are welcome.